# DependencyProperty as List(of String) copies values to all same components

Tags: wpf, vb.net, properties, dependencies, dependency-properties

I have created an dependency property as a List(Of String) in my custom component:

```
Public Shared ReadOnly ErrorCharactersProperty As DependencyProperty = _
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ErrorCharacters", _
    GetType(List(Of String)), _
    GetType(MaterialDesign.TitledTextBox), _
    New UIPropertyMetadata(New List(Of String)))
```

And the property for it:

```
Public Property ErrorCharacters As List(Of String)
    Get
        Return CType(MyBase.GetValue(ErrorCharactersProperty), List(Of String))
    End Get
    Set(value As List(Of String))
        MyBase.SetValue(ErrorCharactersProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property
```

So it should work as a charm and as my other DependencyProperties. The problem is that when I call it and fill my ErrorCharacters with some strings:

```
<MaterialDesign:TitledTextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="246,184,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="187" TitleText="E-Mail">
    <MaterialDesign:TitledTextBox.ErrorCharacters>
        <System:String>@</System:String>
    </MaterialDesign:TitledTextBox.ErrorCharacters>
</MaterialDesign:TitledTextBox>
```

> TitleText is another DependencyProperty that works as it should.

When I call it like this it copies the list to all my other custom components of the same type. I know it cause of controls that I made inside that control. However it copies that List and gives the same result to all other same component of the same type where it shouldn't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that you are passing an actual instance of the list as property default value (which is stored statically), and not a delegate which would provide default value on class instantiation. Hence, if not set explicitly, all instances share the same instance of the list as the value of the property. That being said, if you add an item to the list, it is available/visible to all instances of that type. To resolve this issue you need to set the default property value in the constructor, and not through the property matadata.

Comment: And how I can create a new instance in the component's constructor? Since I can't change properties values in "Shared Public New()" sub? It should be possible to make inside the component so it could be set later by user in XAML without setting it before in code.

Comment: To be honest, I am not familiar with VB, but you need to set the value in non-static constructor (without the `Shared` keyword?).  This prerequisite stems from the fact that the list needs to be instance-specific and not type-specific. You will still be able to change the value in XAML (or not) later on.

Comment: Ok I just did it adding a new Sub New() without shared. Just added it and in code added "ErrorCharacters = new List(Of String)" and it works perfectly. Thank you very much!